# HttpClient.PostAsync HttpContent parameter value null after POSTing data

Tags: c#, http-post, dotnet-httpclient

I have a loop that is iterating through a short list of `URIs` and needs to send each of them the ***same*** content. That `HttpContent` resides in a variable passed into the call to `PostAsync`. The problem I'm incurring is that the *1st* call works perfectly, but all subsequent calls fail because the request content is `null` after the 1st call completes.

I would assume my understanding of the `PostAsync` call under the covers might be lacking some low level detail on the object and it's lifetime (or lack there of) so hopefully someone can shed some light on it for me.

The code looks as follows:

```
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(destionationUri, messageContent).Result;
```

The variable in question is `messageContent` which is of type `MultipartFormDataContent` which derives from `HttpContent`. I suppose some brute method of copying the value to a new and separate location for reuse might work, but I'm looking to understand why this happening and a proper method for allowing the content to persist during the loop.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue, and upon looping around the code above, the `messageContent` value will persist between iterations?

**EDIT:** I went ahead and refactored the code to *rebuild* the `MultipartFormDataContent` from scratch using the same data prior to each call to `PostAsync` using a *new* instance of `HttpClient`. The call to rebuild the `HtppContent` actually worked; the value is not null. However when I now go to make a subsequent call to `PostAsync` and access `.Result` I get the following error:

> Error while copying content to a stream. Cannot access a closed
>   Stream.

**EDIT 2:** Upon inspecting the *2nd* call to my method to rebuild the `MultipartFormDataContent` object from scratch, I notice that my attachment property when inspecting it's `ContentStream` property (of a `Mail.MailMessage` object) states the following:

> attachment.ContentStream.Position threw an exception of type
>   `System.ObjectDisposedException`

All of the properties indicate the `ContentStream` can no longer be read because it's disposed. The call to `PostAsync().Result` apparently is disposing of the stream and is potentially the root issue. However I'm still unable to find a workable solution.

Comment: Can you post some more code? It would be great to see the full example (the loop or the relevant parts) - and I'd like to see what your content actually is and how you initialize and reuse since that's the key to your exceptions. If you're reading from a file maybe you're trying to re-read every time rather than storing the value read or something along those lines.

Comment: Found this post which was similar but not a really good answer I could equate to a workable solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918224/object-is-disposed-after-postasync-with-httpclient

Comment: @JoannaTurban - See if my answer sheds light on anything. As it so happens with some of these questions, there is a bunch of code to post the creation of the request, and paring it down to be meaningful is tough. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Post your http content construction code please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make the solution a bit more tidy by creating a new "wrapper" HttpContent class that allows your content class to be re-used. When sending content, HttpClient automatically disposes any request content, "just in case".  This isn't idea for your case.  Fortunately, the Dispose(bool) method is virtual, so you can override the dispose behaviour in derived class.

```
 public class ReusableContent : HttpContent
    {
        private readonly HttpContent _innerContent;

        public ReusableContent(HttpContent innerContent)
        {
            _innerContent = innerContent;
        }

        protected override async Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
        {
            await _innerContent.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }

        protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
        {
            length = -1;
            return false;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Don't call base dispose
            //base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Once you have this class, you can use it like this,

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task Sending_same_content_multiple_times()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = _BaseAddress };


        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
        sw.Write("This is a stream");
        sw.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var multipart = new MultipartContent
        {
            new StringContent("This string will be sent repeatedly"),
            new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {new KeyValuePair<string, string>("foo", "bar"),}),
            new StreamContent(stream)
        };

        var content = new ReusableContent(multipart);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var response = await client.PostAsync("devnull", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }

    }
```

If you do use this, make sure you don't use an content that does actually need to be disposed without disposing of it manually.

Comment: This should do the trick for a more direct solution, thank you for posting this example.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution and it *works* but is not really the answer I was looking to find. The `ContentStream` as I mentioned once read by the `PostAsync().Result()` was closed/disposed of automatically. Not the behavior I wanted. Even upon trying to rebuild the `MultipartFormDataContent` with the attachment again it was not successful.

This post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8100653/410937 got me thinking to go even *further* up the chain to where the attachments are initially loaded into a `MemoryStream` and re-run that method. The result was a working solution. I essentially have to rebuild the entire request object *completely* from scratch including all native and raw elements, and *then* `POST` again.

Seems to much to me as I just wanted to loop and `POST` to 1..n `URIs` using the same content. All the nuances made me walk all the way back up the line to rebuild the request content from scratch to make it work.

The solution if existed I was really seeking was more along the following:

1. Notify `PostAsync().Result()` to *not* close my stream after reading
2. Resurrect the file attachment stream to be readable again without having to recreate the entire request. Although since it was disposed this was probably not feasible.

I'm open to a more direct solution but this does actually work.